# How to select a table row without using classes or pseudo classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to select the third row of a table without using a pseudo class or without applying a class to the row (it's more to exercise the workings of the siblings operators).

But it also applies to the fourth and following rows.

```css
tbody > tr + tr + tr {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
            <tr><td>World</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Should be blue</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Should not be blue</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why don't want to you use `nth-child (3)` ?

Comment: I want to understand better how the `+` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without *pseudo* selector? Well you can use `color: initial` on `tbody > tr + tr + tr + tr` (you can *reset* all the properties you have applied on the third `tr` in this selector by using `initial` - see demo below:

```css
tbody > tr + tr + tr {
    color: blue; /* styles for the third row */
}
tbody > tr + tr + tr + tr{
    color: initial; /* reset all the styles applied in the third row here */
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
            <tr><td>World</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Should be blue</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Should not be blue</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I thought that must be it, still wondering why the selector is "greedy"

Comment: Because it matches two scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, It works if you don't want to use pseudo class or without applying a class to the row.

```
tbody > tr + tr + tr + tr {
    color: initial;
}

tbody > tr + tr + tr {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: copy from above answer

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Your rule matches *any* group of three siblings, not just the first group.

---

### Explanation

The CSS **adjacent sibling combinator** (`+`) targets an element *immediately* following a sibling element.

For contrast, the **general sibling combinator** (`~`) targets an element following a sibling element (it doesn't have to be next).

The problem with your rule is that it matches two scenarios.

Here's your code:

```css
tbody > tr + tr + tr {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>World</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>Should be blue</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>Should not be blue</td></tr>    
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

`tr + tr + tr` means: *select a table row that immediately follows a table row, that also immediately follows a table row.*  You have four rows, so that situation exists twice in your code:

*match 1*

[image]

*match 2*

[image]

Other potential matches:

- If you had one row, the rule would match 0 times.
- If you had two rows, the rule would match 0 times.
- If you had three rows, the rule would match one time.
- If you had five rows, the rule would match three times.
- If you had six rows, the rule would match four times.
- and so on...

CSS IDs, classes and `pseudo-classes` exist to help you out in these sorts of situations.

MDN references:

- [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)
- [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)